# Returning multiple dropdown values in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'd like to build an application where the user selects their first favorite food and second favorite food from two different dropdown lists in React.  I built the dropdown with reactjs-dropdown-component, and have it sitting in a script separate from my main App.  After the user selects their two favorite foods I would like them to submit it and print it to the console.  I'm not sure how to retrieve the value since the actual dropdown values are in a separate script.

Here is the dropdown script:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {DropdownMultiple, Dropdown} from 'reactjs-dropdown-component';

class FavoriteFood extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            food: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    title: 'Pizza',
                    selected: false,
                    key: 'food'
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Cookies',
                    selected: false,
                    key: 'food'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Apples',
                    selected: false,
                    key: 'food'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'Yogurt',
                    selected: false,
                    key: 'food'
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    title: 'Crackers',
                    selected: false,
                    key: 'food'
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    title: 'Bread',
                    selected: false,
                    key: 'food'
                },
                {
                    id: 6,
                    title: 'Cheese',
                    selected: false,
                    key: 'food'
                },
            ],
        }
    }

    toggleSelected = (id, key) => {
        let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state[key]));
        temp[id].selected = !temp[id].selected;
        this.setState({
          [key]: temp
        })
      }

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={{width: '15%', display: 'inline-block', padding: '10px'}}>
                <DropdownMultiple
                    titleHelper="Food"
                    title="Favorite Food"
                    list={this.state.food}
                    toggleItem={this.toggleSelected}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
  }

export default FavoriteFood
```

And here is the main App script:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FavoriteFood from './favoriteFood.js';


class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={

        }
    }


    getValues(){
        console.log(document.getElementById('firstFav').value)
        console.log(document.getElementById('secondFav').value)
    }


    render () {
        return (
            <FavoriteFood id='firstFav' />
            <FavoriteFood id='secondFav' />
            <button onClick={() => getValues()}>Print Values</button>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

When I use this appraoch I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null'.  I assume there is a better way I should be doing this, just can't think of how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using React, try to refrain from using plain JS and DOM manipulation, instead, use the tools that React offer.

The solution to your problem, is adding a `prop` to `FavoriteFood`, which is called whenever you select a different food, and then, on the parent component (in this case `App`), you add them to state.

Updated function in `FavoriteFood`:

```
toggleSelected = (id, key) => {
        let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state[key]));
        temp[id].selected = !temp[id].selected;
        this.setState({
          [key]: temp
        })
        this.props.updateSelection({[key]: temp})
      }
```

And then, in App, instead of trying to get the updated values from the DOM, get them from the child component:

```
render () {
        return (
            <FavoriteFood id='firstFav' onUpdate={updateFood} />
            <FavoriteFood id='secondFav' onUpdate={updateFood} />
            <button onClick={() => getValues()}>Print Values</button>
        )
    }
```

And `updateFood` should look like this:

```
const updateFood = (foodObj) => {
    this.setState({
        ...foodObj
    });
}
```

And from now on, on every update, you'll have your data within the `App`'s state.